# How do you create 2 separate Numbered Lists within the same document? (Word 2016)

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I create two Numbered Lists within the same Word document, one List for {1, ..., 95}  and the other for {1, 2, ..., 65} (in the bolded)? It is too inefficient to type one set manually, while you use this feature for only the other set.

> **Part 1**
>
> 1.
>   ⋮
>   3.
>
> **Part 2**
>
> 4.
>
> ⋮
>
> **Part 64**
>
> 81.
>   ⋮
>   88.
>
> **Part 65**
>
> 89.
>   ⋮
>   95.

Answer (score 5):

**Use Multi-level List**

First, it's a good practice that you finish writing your list completely and continuously without numbering and without text lines that are not list items. This should avoid converting numbers to default options which may not work well to give what you expect.

Highlight all your un-numbered lists and from the Home tab on the Ribbon, click the arrow with the Multi-level list button (grouped under Paragraph, 3rd from left). From the context menu it has, pick `Define new multi-level list`. And before you change anything from the dialogue box, click the `More >>` button at the bottom.

From `Click level to modify` at the top-left, pick `1`.

Below it at `Enter formatting for number` space, clear it and and write `Part` (with space).

Below it at `Number style for this level`, select a numbering system. Your done with this level.

Go back at `Click level to modify` at the top-left and pick `2`.

At `Enter formatting for number` space, clear it.

At `Number style for this level`, select a numbering system.

At `Enter formatting for number` space, put the cursor at the end (Keyboard END) and type in a fullstop `.`.

On the right, un-tick `Restart list after`. Your done with this level so confirm your changes.

Now highlight the list items that should lie under Part 1, for example.

Click the arrow with the Multi-level list button (grouped under Paragraph, 3rd from left). From the context menu it has, pick `Change list level` and pick the second level. Repeat it with the other sub-items in you list.

If you want to insert normal text lines between 2 list items, put the cursor at the end of the upper item list. Press Keyboard ENTER 3 times till the cursor moves to the beginning of the new line. This will maintain correct numbering through all your document.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> brings a numbering level up to the same line.  For example:

```
1.    (a)    text;
      (b)    text; etc.
```